# Numpy 1D array - find indices of boundaries of subsequences of the same number

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `numpy.array` made by zeros and ones, e.g.:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

And now I need to get the first and last index of 1 in each sequence of ones. If I use `where`, I can get indices of each 1 in the array:

```
ones = numpy.where(a == 1)
# ones = (array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17], dtype=int64),)
```

But I would like to get only boundaries, it means:

```
# desired:
ones = (array([ 3,  6,  9, 10, 14, 17], dtype=int64),)
```

Could you please help me, how to achieve this result? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps diff and then find the nonzero indices? Those would indicate a value change.

Comment: I am sorry, it sounds like it should be simple, but would you be so kind and python me a solution? I will check it as the answer, but I don't know what do you precisely mean. I am a numpy newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the beginning and end of these sequences shifting and comparing using bitwise operators and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get the corresponding indices:

```
def first_and_last_seq(x, n):
    a = np.r_[n-1,x,n-1]
    a = a==n
    start = np.r_[False,~a[:-1] & a[1:]]
    end = np.r_[a[:-1] & ~a[1:], False]
    return np.where(start|end)[0]-1
```

---

Checking with the proposed example:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
first_and_last_seq(a, 1)
# array([ 3,  6,  9, 10, 14, 17])
```

Or with the following array:

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,6,2,3,5,5,5,2,3,5,5])
first_and_last_seq(a, 5)
# array([ 3,  6,  9, 10, 14, 17])
```

---

**Further details**:

A simple way to check for consecutive values in numpy, is to use [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) to compare *shifted* versions of an array. Note that `~a[:-1] & a[1:]` is doing precesely that. The first term is the array sliced up till the last element, and the second term a slice from the first element onwards.

Note that `a` is a boolean array, given `a = a==n`. In the above case we are taking a `NOT` of the first shifted boolean array (since we want a `True` is the value is `False`. And by taking a bitwise `AND` with the next value, we will only have `True` is the next sample is `True` This way we set to `True` only the indices where the sequences start (i.e. we've matched the subsequence `[False, True]`)

Now the same logic applies for `end`. And by taking an `OR` of both arrays and `np.where` on the result we get all start and end indices.

Comment: Wow, it is working like a charm. But, could you, please, a bit explain it? I don't understand, why it is working and what your source code really does.

Comment: Let me add some details @Honza

Comment: Hope its  a little clearer with the details @Honza

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I understand now :-)