# efficient ways to find start and end indexes for sequences?

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

So lets say I have a list in python:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and I want to find the indices where 1's start and end, eg:

```
[[4, 5], [8, 13], [16, 16], [18, 21]]
```

What is an efficient way to do this in python? All I can think of are expensive for loops where I look forward/backward if the iteration shows a 1 and before it was a 0? Perhaps a cumsum? But that would still require a loop.

Also, would this problem change if I were to add rules? like there must be at least 3 consecutive 1's before its recorded, eg:

```
[[8, 13], [18, 21]]
```

or there must be 3 consecutive instances of any digit before a change in pattern is recorded or stopped, eg:

```
[[8, 21]]
```

My problem is with lists of characters, but the core of it can be boiled down to this mindset.

My inefficient solution is to scan through with some padding:

```
answer = []
record_flag = 0
vec = [0] + vec + [0]
for i in range(len(vec)-1):
    if vec[i] == 0 and vec[i+1] == 1:
        start = i
        record_flag += 1
    elif vec[i] == 1 and vec[i+1] == 0:
        end = i-1
        record_flag += 1

    if record_flag >= 2:
        record_flag = 0
        answer.append([start, end])
```

and if I need to add rules, I'd just manually insert them into the if-statements. But this does not feel very pythonic. Any advice?

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760669/numpy-1d-array-find-indices-of-boundaries-of-subsequences-of-the-same-number) will help you regarding the first question. It depends on bitwise operations. you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151417/numpy-find-indices-of-groups-with-same-value)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear that, Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to solve your first two questions. It first finds the segments and their length and then computes start positions of each segment. Finally segments are filtered out (in the two `print` statements) first by their value, and second by value and length.

```
from itertools import groupby

vec = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

# find sequences and lengths
# seqs = [(key, length), ...]
seqs = [(key, len(list(val))) for key, val in groupby(vec)]
# find start positions of sequences
# seqs = [(key, start, length), ...]
seqs = [(key, sum(s[1] for s in seqs[:i]), len) for i, (key, len) in enumerate(seqs)]

print([[s[1], s[1] + s[2] - 1] for s in seqs if s[0] == 1])
print([[s[1], s[1] + s[2] - 1] for s in seqs if s[0] == 1 and s[2] > 2])
```

Output:

```
[[4, 5], [8, 13], [16, 16], [18, 21]]
[[8, 13], [18, 21]]
```